# Is the $\text{Dirichlet}(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ distribution truly the distribution of an $n$-dimensional random vector?

Tags: probability

Suppose $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim \text{Dirichlet}(a_1, a_2, a_3)$. Then the density of this random vector is proportional to $$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \propto x_1^{a_1 - 1} x_2^{a_2 - 1} x_3^{a_3 - 1}$$
on the $2$-simplex: $K_2 := \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1, x_i \geq 0.\}$

Technically speaking, isn't it the case that $$\int_{K_2} f\ dV = 0?$$
I say this because the volume of a $2$-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is zero. Doesn't this mean that $f$ is not the density of probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: To define your measure from this density, you should not use $dV$, you should use surface area $dA$ on the simplex.  Correct:   Considered as a measure on $\mathbb R^3$, it is a **singular measure**, so it does not have a density with respect to $dV$.  It has a density with respect to $dA$, so $$C\int_{K_2\cap E} f\ dA = \mathbb{P}((X_1,X_2,X_3) \in E)$$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you very much. Could you please recommend a reference so I can learn about this? Will any measure theory book do?

Comment: Look in the index of a measure theory book for "singular measure".

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. What is the measure dA here? Is this a surface measure?